# General Approach to Solving Cryptarithms

Tags: strategy, alphametic

I have recently started honing my problem-solving skills, starting with number-related puzzles. Cryptarithms have appeared frequently, so I was wondering whether there is some sort of general approach to solving these problems? Such as a sequence of reproducible steps?

I understand that for easier examples, such as "AB + AB + AB = CB" , common sense can be used to recognise simple facts (in this case, B must be 0 or 5). However, for harder examples that involve multiple solutions or higher-digit numbers, I find myself struggling without making any progress.

Guidance on how to approach these problems would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kinds of operations are involved in your cryptarithms? Addition and subtraction only, or also multiplication, division, etc.?

Comment: My suggestion: click on the `alphametic` tag and have a look at some of the previously asked alphametic questions. Read the solutions with your question in mind: is there a general approach? What are some strategies that appear frequently?

Comment: @bobble Mainly addition...

Comment: For those concerned with topicality, a [relevant meta discussion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/159/)